# "angular is not defined" while debugging the Typescript code using Visual Studio code

Tags: angularjs, typescript1.6, visual-studio-code

I downloaded the code from https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-TypeScript and then performed the following steps:

1. Opened the code using Visual Studio Code (version:0.9.1)
2. Extended the code with other features.
3. Executed the command shown in the below screenshot to generate the source map files.
   [image]

4.Executed the step to create the launch.json for debugging the code

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    // List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.
    // ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
            "name": "Launch app.ts",
            // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
            "type": "node",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
            "program": "app/app.ts",
            // Automatically stop program after launch.
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            // Command line arguments passed to the program.
            "args": [],
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
            "cwd": ".",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
            // Environment variables passed to the program.
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
            "sourceMaps": true,
            // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
            "address": "localhost",
            // Port to attach to.
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

I now pressed the Ctrl + Shift + D command and tried to debug the code. The control goes to the app.ts file and there it stops with the following exception:"angular is not defined"

[image]

Can anyone help me to know is there anything I am missing to fix the issue.

Comment: Try setting the "outDir" value to "." in both launch.json and tsconfig.json as I show here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/visual-studio-code/discussion

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried the above but it is still not working for me.